# Objective c can not catch exception from calling super method

Tags: objective-c, try-catch, super

I am calling a super method from my subclass. But sometimes the object of the superclass (UIWindow) is nil so it will fail. I try to catch the exception but it doesn´t work. The app still crashes. Can anyone tell me why and how I can fix this?

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event;  
{
     @try {
         [super sendEvent:event];
     }
     @catch(NSException *e) {
         NSLog(@"%@",e);
         return;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Exceptions in Objective-C are used for irrecoverable situations. This means that you can still use them, but consider that they slow down the program, and that the convention implies to use NSError instead.

Comment: "But sometimes the object of the superclass (UIWindow) is nil so it will fail." What fails? Why should something fail if it's `nil`? What do you mean by "fail"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What exception are you trying to catch?

If it is something like `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, then that is a hard crash and cannot be caught with `@catch`.

Otherwise?  You are going to have to post more information.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you, I remove my answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yeah I get a bad access, thought I could catch this one in any way.